# Debian package builds in my computer, but fails to build in Launchpad and pbuilder - "msgfmt: cannot locate ITS rules"

Tags: 20.04, deb, packaging, launchpad

I made a [debian package](https://github.com/apandada1/blanket/) for [Blanket](https://github.com/rafaelmardojai/blanket), and tried to build it with Launchpad recipe.

While it builds successfully in my computer (Xubuntu 20.04), it [fails to build](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/496506049/buildlog_ubuntu-focal-amd64.blanket_0.2.0-0%7E202009060906%7Eubuntu20.04.1_BUILDING.txt.gz) for focal in Launchpad.
Here is the relevant part of the buildlog.

```
Found ninja-1.10.0 at /usr/bin/ninja
   dh_auto_build
    cd obj-x86_64-linux-gnu && LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ninja -j4 -v
[1/3] glib-compile-resources ../data/resources/blanket.gresource.xml --sourcedir ../data/resources --internal --generate --target data/resources/blanket.gresource --dependency-file data/resources/blanket.gresource.d
xml-stripblanks preprocessing requested, but XMLLINT is not set, and xmllint is not in PATH
[2/3] /usr/bin/meson --internal msgfmthelper ../data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.metainfo.xml.in data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.metainfo.xml xml ../data/../po
FAILED: data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.metainfo.xml 
/usr/bin/meson --internal msgfmthelper ../data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.metainfo.xml.in data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.metainfo.xml xml ../data/../po
msgfmt: cannot locate ITS rules for ../data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.metainfo.xml.in
[3/3] /usr/bin/meson --internal msgfmthelper ../data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.desktop.in data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.desktop desktop ../data/../po
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

In my computer (when I run `debuild`), the relevant part of the output is

```
Found ninja-1.10.0 at /usr/bin/ninja
   dh_auto_build
    cd obj-x86_64-linux-gnu && LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ninja -j4 -v
[1/3] glib-compile-resources ../data/resources/blanket.gresource.xml --sourcedir ../data/resources --internal --generate --target data/resources/blanket.gresource --dependency-file data/resources/blanket.gresource.d
xml-stripblanks preprocessing requested, but XMLLINT is not set, and xmllint is not in PATH
[2/3] /usr/bin/meson --internal msgfmthelper ../data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.desktop.in data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.desktop desktop ../data/../po
[3/3] /usr/bin/meson --internal msgfmthelper ../data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.metainfo.xml.in data/com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket.metainfo.xml xml ../data/../po
   dh_auto_test
    cd obj-x86_64-linux-gnu && LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 MESON_TESTTHREADS=4 ninja test
[0/1] Running all tests.
1/2 Validate desktop file                   OK       0.01 s 
2/2 Validate schema file                    OK       0.01 s 

Ok:                    2
```

and the build continues successfully. As suggested by [this](https://github.com/bilelmoussaoui/nautilus-git/issues/25#issuecomment-309259170), I added `libappstream-glib-dev` to the `build-depends` field, but that did not work.

I am getting the same error inside a `pbuilder` chroot environment.
Am I missing some build dependency when I build it in Launchpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing build dependency was `appstream` (not `libappstream-glib-dev`). It has to be added to `build-depends` in `debian/control`.

Thanks to [Colin Watson](https://askubuntu.com/users/3228/colin-watson), who provided this information in [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/692788).